# I am trying to study moon position so that I can predict which direction which angle should I view from my small balcony to view moon

Tags: moon, climate-science

I have a small window through which I can view the moon only at some times for few minutes,I am keen to understand and study moon positioning to predict when shall be the next day I shall view moon through my window ,I tried studying moon position, azimuth,moon rise and moon set and the cycle of moon which is 29.5 days so I shall definitely view my moon after 59 days from the day I view the moon from my window but wanted to predict if it happens anytime before that

Comment: The [motion of the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_theory) is rather complicated, so you can't predict its exact position with simple equations. But you can use a programs like Stellarium (which is free). And there's NASA's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/) system. If you *do* want to calculate the Moon's position, and you're familiar with JavaScript, take a look at Greg Miller's code, https://www.celestialprogramming.com/ Greg is active on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am not affiliated with this app, but I do like it: "Star Chart." It shows you exactly which planets, stars, etc. are at which positions in the sky by pointing your phone at the sky (or the ground, or wherever). You can also search for "The Moon" and the app will tell you where to point your phone (and your eyes) to see the moon.

Comment: Also, what is your question? You have not written a question...

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do this is to use a [nautical almanac](https://thenauticalalmanac.com/TNACompact/2024_Nautical_Almanac_compact_version.pdf) (Look on page 14 for the moon position).  This is how sailors find their position. It tells you the exact position of the moon every second of the year.

And if you look at this [sextant users guide](http://iodlabs.ucsd.edu/mrk/Sailing/Sextant_Users_GuideV4.pdf) (which I wrote) you will see how to work with the almanac to find the moon's position exactly.  The guide was written for the sun, but the moon's position works in exactly the same way. I specifically wrote the guide to be very easy to understand.

What I would do is find a date and time when you can see the moon out your window.  Then find that date and time in the almanac and you can then find the position of the moon.    Then you can use the almanac to find any future times when the moon will be in that same position.